# Starting adb daemon python

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess, adb

I'm developing a ADB client for python, i am planning to invoke adb binary with sub process to get the information.

Here is how i tried to invoke it, to start the adb server.

```
check_output([ 'adb.exe','start-server'],stderr=STDOUT)
```

I do see the adb running, but the program is getting stuck after that.
I have tried with `shell=True`, but that didn't affect it.

When i kill adb from task manager, the program does exit, and prints the right ouput.

How can i fix this, I assume that the command doesn't exit since the daemon is running ?

I was able to overcome this by starting the command in a separate thread, and using the current thread with other adb commands, as they return immediately.
Is there a more elegant solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor).

```
import subprocess

adb = subprocess.Popen(['adb.exe', 'start-server'])
# Do some other stuff while adb is running...

adb.terminate()  # Kill the process once you're done
```

This also has some advantages, like the possibility of giving input to the process through stdin, by using [`Popen.communicate()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate)